# Use JQuery to make a call and bring back multiple status

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, shell

I'm wondering if this is possible. I'm using jQuery to run a Java servlet that runs a shell script. The script takes about 2 minute to run and echos a message every 30 seconds. I want to return each of those messages to the web page in real time. So say I have this sh:

```
sleep 30
echo "status 1"
sleep 30
echo "status 2"
```

you get the picture. I am grabbing the messages now, but I'm just returning all the status when the job is complete. Is there a way to display the messages on the page as they happen?

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of a way. I will write the status echos to a temp file and then create another ajax call that runs synchronously to ping that file for status updates and display them. Please let me know if there is a better way.